# Understanding Sessions in Python requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm new to making HTTP requests so a lot of what I read in the requests library documentation goes over my head. I'm trying to automate the downloading of a number of files and, from what I understand, if I use `requests.Sessions()` and then `get()` each file (the first example below), requests will maintain a connection with the server and the process will go faster. Without using `requests.Sessions()` (the second example), the code will establish a new connection to the server for each `get()`. Is this a proper understanding of what is going on in the two examples below?

**Example with `requests.Session()`**

```
import requests

urls = ['https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/full-index/2016/QTR1/master.idx',
    'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/full-index/2016/QTR2/master.idx',
    'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/full-index/2016/QTR3/master.idx']

with requests.Session() as s:
    for url in urls:
        doc = s.get(url)

        # Process file
```

**Example without `requests.Session()`**

```
import requests

urls = ['https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/full-index/2016/QTR1/master.idx',
    'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/full-index/2016/QTR2/master.idx',
    'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/full-index/2016/QTR3/master.idx']

for url in urls:
    doc = requests.get(url)

    # Process file
```

Comment: Session is mainly used when an authentication with the server is required - so in that case you have a cookie and you use that to communicate with the server. If no authentication is required then there is nothing wrong with the second way also. An even more detailed and better explanation is given here: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects

Comment: Thanks. So using `Session()` won't add any sort of gains to requests to the same server if I'm not trying to get cookies or other parameters to persist from request to request? I had read through that document but the part that says, "So if you're making several requests to the same host, the underlying TCP connection will be reused, which can result in a significant performance increase." This lead me to believe it would be useful for me.

Comment: No, if we are talking about multiple requests to the same server, then of course you will have a performance increase, but if for example you wanted to create a web-crawler then Session wouldn't be much of use. The performance increase has to do with the use of cookies - in this way the server already knows you and the transactions are performed faster.

Comment: Session is also very useful if for example you want to post or get a lot of data without corruption, imagine for example that you want to post a file to a server, the server process the data and return back to you the results. In this case a session is required (e.g. post a file for a scan etc...).